# Excel Normal Layout: Horizontally Centered

Tags: microsoft-excel, layout

**Description of Problem**

I have an excel form, which people fill out and submit. I have made it very user friendly, and protected it, even removing the "ribbon" formatting bar at the top. I would like to be able to centre the cells (there are only 6 columns, the rest are hidden) so that it looks kind of like Word, with margins on the left and right. I can't use "Page Layout", because the printing format isn't as clean looking as the normal layout.

If this isn't possible, are there better ways to distribute excel sheets?

**This is what it looks like:**
[image: This is How it appears (minus the form content)]

**This is what I want it to look like:**
[image: This is How I want it to appear (minus the form content)]

Comment: Could you possibly make an image of what you are looking for?  Possibly an annotated spreadsheet or (even) a poorly drawn image in MS Paint?

Comment: @RLH I added some pics. I hope this helps.

Comment: You can not do that. Excel is a spreadsheet application and has it limits. If you absolutely need it, better to look for a more suitable tool.